# How to stop download in hook_file_download

Tags: 8, hooks

I'm building a page with different download buttons linked to private zip files. Users have to log in to download. I am using module [Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term) to manage who can see which button.
I added a field to user entity to log each download. In hook_file_download() I check, if and how often this file is already downloaded by this user. Up to here everything works fine.
I want to stop or block the download and show a message to the user, if download counter reaches 5 or 10. Is hook_file_download the right hook to achieve this?

Comment: Check the hook documentation. If you return -1, it won’t serve the file.

Comment: Thanks, but @STF solution is cleaner for me. Actually I can omit the message and redirect the user to a page with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this to check that the users has remaining downloads or redirect them to an upgrade page.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 */
function mymodule_file_download($uri) {
  // Check if user is logged in
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
    // Load entity of current user
    $current_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

    // Check if current user is: access || student || (professional && trial_actived)
    $download_control = $current_user->hasRole('professional') && $current_user->field_user_free_trial->value == 'trial_actived' ? TRUE : FALSE;
    $download_control = $download_control || $current_user->hasRole('access') || $current_user->hasRole('student') ? TRUE : FALSE;

if ($download_control) {

  // Declare files that decrease the counter
  $controlled_uris = [
    'private://mechanisms/files',
  ];

  // Check if requested uri matches with controlled uris
  foreach ($controlled_uris as $c_uri) {
    if (strpos($uri, $c_uri) !== FALSE) {

      // Check if user still has remaining downloads
      if ($current_user->field_user_download_counter->value > 0) {

        // Decrease user downloads counter
        $current_user->field_user_download_counter->value--;
        $current_user->save();
      }
      else {
        // Prepare redirect url to the prices page
        $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 39])->toString();

        // Set message
        $message = t('Your account has reached the maximum limit of downloads.');
        \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning($message);

        // Send response to url
        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($url);
        $response->send();
      }
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```